# Closed-form of a sequence (forward induction)

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, solution-verification, closed-form

I am trying to prove a result using forward induction and I get the following expressions for each round:

- first: $a$
- second: $a+b(1-a)$
- third: $a^2(1-b) +b^2(1-a) + ab$
- fourth: (a bit too cumbersome and I stopped to figure if I already had something concrete)

Alternatively, we can get the following (equivalent) expressions for the respective rounds:

- first: $a$
- second: $a^2 + (1-a)(b+a)$
- third: $a^2 + (1-a)(b+a)b$

These theoretical results are in line with simulations. Does it follow some traditional math form/expansion? (something like a binomial-like expansion or so...) Not a mathematician here...

Further info (if needed):

- $\frac{1}{2} \leq a \leq 1$,
- $0 \leq b \leq \frac{1}{2}$,
- $a = (1-\mu)\theta + \mu\gamma$,
- $b=(1-\mu)\theta + \mu(1-\gamma)$.
- $0 \leq \mu \leq1$, $0 \leq \theta \leq 1$ and $\frac{1}{2} < \gamma \leq 1$.

Comment: Maybe you can try $(a+b)^{n-1} - ab(a+b+1)^{n-2}$ for $n\geq 2$. It does not correspond to your first case, though.  
Your case $n=2$ is equivalent to $a+b - ab=(a+b)^1 - ab(a+b-1)^0$ and
your case $n=3$ is equivalent to $(a+b)^2 - ab ( a + b +1)^1$. 
Not enough information to think deeper about the second term. Could also be $(a+b)^{n-1} - ab((a+b)^{n-2}+1)$.

Comment: @Jfischer, thx and sorry for taking long to reply. Was double checking it and managed to expand to $t=4$. However, I managed to do it for a slightly different expression. First term: $(1-a)$, Second term: $(1-a)(1-b)$, Third term: $(1-a)[(1-b)+(1-a)(a+b)]$, Fourth term: $(1-a)[(1-b)^2(1+b) + (1-a)(1-b)(a+b)]$. Your thoughts are more than welcome.